# Shortest distance from a point to non-standard hyperbola

Tags: geometry

How to get the shortest distance from a point $p$ to the non standard hyperbola (the hyperbola center is translated to $(h,k)$ and is not parallel to $x$ or $y$ axis). Thanks

Comment: http://www.sosmath.com/CBB/viewtopic.php?t=17029

Comment: @labbhattacharjee. Thanks. However in my case, the hyperbola is given rotated at $\theta$, so I cannot change it to remove $xy$.

Comment: In what form is your hyperbola given? As an equation in $x,y$ having numerical coefficients? If so maybe look at the squared distance from $p$ to a point on the hyperbola, and try to find the critical point.

Comment: @coffeemath, The hyperbola is given in general form $\frac{\{(x-h)cos\theta+(y-k)sin\theta\}^2}{a^2}-\frac{\{-(x-h)sin\theta+(y-k)cos\theta\}^2}{b^2}=1$. Thanks in advance

Comment: hidayat: I don't know how hard it would be, but in the form of your last comment you have the hyperbola as a one variable function of $\theta,$ where $a,b,h,k$ are arbitrary constants. So things are ready for one variable calculus-- find derivative, critical points, etc. May be a mess.. I didn't try it. OOPS that's only the hyperbola itself, so I take what I just said back! one would now form a two variable function as squared distance from given point $p$ to the hyperbola, maybe then use two variable critical point methods.